# Cooling a laser

Tags: laser

In a 4-level system why would cooling reduce the lasing threshold? I thought the threshold was determined by things like mirror reflectivity and absorption and scattering losses, it isn't obvious to me why those would be particularly affected by temperature.

Comment: In a gas, Doppler broadening and collision broadening would increase with temperature.

Comment: In a solid-state 4-level system, there are likely phonon-mediated paths for relaxation from the level that lasing takes place out of. The cooler the laser medium is, the lower the non-radiative losses in the system, the lower the threshold for lasing since you don't have to pump as hard.